# How to order by computed column in new dto query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have this query:

```
em.createQuery("select new SomeDto(some.name, " +
"(select max(other.weight) from Other other where other.someId = some.id) as otherWeight" +
") from Some some order by otherWeight")
.getResultList();
```

Which does not work because hibernate ignores the `as otherWeight` and simply generates `as col_1_0_` instead.

Is there any way with this kind of `select new dto` query to get aliases for columns?
If not: how can i do such a query (map result of query to DTO constructor)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following query, which should also be faster:

```
select new SomeDto(some.name, max(other.weight))
from Other other right outer join other.some some
group by some.id, some.name
order by max(other.weight)
```

You need to introduce the many-to-one (or one-to-one) association from `Other` to `Some` if you don't have one already.

Comment: this works if there is always an `Other` for each `Some` but in case this is optional I would exclude those results (inner join) right?

Comment: You're probably right. My initial goal was to somehow use an alias in the "order by" clause to make the whole thing more readable (imagine that instead of `max(other.weight)` there is some more complex expression) however, it seems that this is something one would need more in "pure sql" if you write queries by hand a lot. When constructing such jpql queries such expressions could be put into variables and concatenated that way to still keep it readable. So I think there isn't really a solution for what I wanted because it isn't something one "should want".